# NLog and custom exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

I'm new to NLog and I've never used an advanced logging library before. My question may seem stupid but I really want to know how and what's the best way to log custom exceptions with custom properties. Should I create a LayoutRenderer for each exception type or is there any better way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess it that you do not want to write a custom LayoutRenderer for each exception type.  The reason being that you probably want to define a single logging format for your log file.  For example:

```
${date} | ${logger} | ${level} | ${message} | ${exception}
```

It would be very difficult to manage the formatting using many different LayoutRenderers for the exceptions.  If you have a lot of custom LayoutRenderers, you might consider writing a single custom LayoutRenderer that can understand all of the custom exceptions that you have.  Or, you might make a generic LayoutRenderer that can interpret any exception via reflection.

See this [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248434/logging-exception-properties) here on SO for some ideas about how to log custom exception information with NLog.

One of ideas presented is to write a custom LayoutRenderer that uses reflection to find the exception's properties and values and log them.

Another idea, that doesn't involve writing any extra code, is to try [NLog's Exception renderer](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Exception_layout_renderer).  One of its options is to use the ToString option (I think you specify it like this:  `${exception:tostring}`.  If your custom exceptions (and "normal" exceptions as well) provide enough information in their `ToString` method, that might be sufficient.